# Could not connect to Oracle 12c server from a website when hosted in Web server. Null Reference exception thrown

Tags: oracle, web-applications, oracle11g, oracle12c

We have recently migrated our database from Oracle 11g to 12c in PROD. Hence, in our Website, I have changed the ConnectionString to connect the new server. But, it is throwing error to connect in PROD server. The error is thrown when doing to the Oracle DB call.

```
Code: Changed only the host names in below connection string: 

<add key="ConnectStringOracle_p" value="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST= (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXX-scan.astrazeneca.net)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = scp))); User Id=aaaa; Password=samplepwd"/>

  DB Call:
         try
            {
                Oracle oracle = this.ConfigureOracle(new Oracle(connectString));

                    System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection con = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectString);
                    System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand cmd = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand(command, con);

                    foreach (AZ.CISS.ARCH.DBController.Parameter p in param)
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Key) && p.Value != null)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.Key.Trim(), p.Value);
                    }

                    System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter apap = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                    returnTable = new ExtendedDataTable();
                    apap.Fill(ds);
            }
```

Error when 32 Bit oracle client v12.2 used:
*SOURCE: System.Data.OracleClient MESSAGE: Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed*

Error when 64 Bit client v12.2 used:
*SOURCE: System.Data.OracleClient MESSAGE: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied*

During testing, I did the same config file change in pre-prod and everything worked fine without any issues.

On comparison, I found pre-prod has Oracle client 12.1 64bit installed and Prod has 11.2 64 bit installed. I installed 12.2 bit now in PROD environment and still I am facing issue in connecting. (Note: I installed V12.2 thinking 12.2 will be better compatible with Oracle 12c database. Should I try oracle client V12.1 installed?)

Below are the details of those servers:
Both PROD and Pre-Prod - 2012 R2 server
Oracle Client -> 12.1 64Bit in PROD and 12.2v 64Bit in Pre-Prod

For other Windows Applications, I was getting "Invalid Username/Password error" which cleared after using oracle.manageddataaccess.dll. But I can't change the dll in this website since this is an old application and needs lots of code changes.

I guess this is an Oracle Client error. But not sure how to rectify this.

Edit: ISSUE FIXED!!!!
Looks like it was a dumb one. It was an issue in the DB side. The "password versions" should have been "10G 11G 12C" in the "dba_users" table. Instead it was "11G 12C" which caused the issue in connecting via Oracle client. I got this from several other articles where they mentioned changing SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8 in sqlnet.ora file in server and resetting the password will help. Luckily for me, SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER was still = 11. Just resetting the password did the trick and now I am able to see the password versions as "10G 11G 12C". I was kicking my leg for this simple fix. Updating this, so other people might find the issue sooner. Note: DO NOT FORGET TO RESET THE PASSWORD!!!!!!

Comment: what error exactly is thrown? at which action of your source-code? how do you connect (code)?

Comment: Your versions in the questions are not matching, you say first you installed 12.2 in prod, but later it's 12.1. You also talk about pre-prod, but then suddenly UAT appears. Are those the same environment?

Comment: @MichaelHauptmann I have updated the question with the details requested. Hope this is much clear. Pardon me, since I am new to this.

Comment: The code uses Microsoft-Netframework for DB-Access (could be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection?view=netframework-4.8) ... which is deprecated for a very long time. i assume MS uses dynamic linking to the oracle-client, which is prone to fail if oracle>netframework.
Easiest solution could be to leave the oracle-client on the web-server at the old 11g Version. There is absolutely no need to upgrade the client if server-version is upgraded, the server is backwards compatible. newly introduced features will be not available

Comment: "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied" hints that the oracle/ms dll´s somehow arrange their existence, but the db-auth fails. the code-snippet uses no user/pwd, windows-authentication might be used. maybe your new webserver is running in a user-context currently not known in the oracle-server or missing the required windows-role (https://developer.oracle.com/dotnet/cook-mastering-dotnet.html). (content of "this.ConfigureOracle" might set the password. oracle-login was enhanced since 11g, might cause the trouble )

Comment: The issue is fixed now. Looks like it was a dumb one. It was an issue in the DB side. The "password versions" should have been "10G 11G 12C" in the "dba_users" table.  Instead it was "11G 12C" which caused the issue in connecting via Oracle client. I got this from another article where they mentioned changing SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8 in sqlnet.ora file in server and  resetting the password will help. Luckily for me, SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER was still = 11. Just resetting the password did the trick and now I am able to see the password versions as "10G 11G 12C".